# webpack 4 config, reloading page crashes

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Trying to migrate to webpack 4 (from 3).
I have tried with a very basic config, it works properly when running `webpack-dev-server --mode development` but when I enter admin subpage (localhost:3000/admin/test) and reload page, it crashes. It wants to find the main.js file in /admin/main.js, but it is located in /main.js.

Following error is received:
`Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/admin/main.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

Any idea?

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

module.exports = (env) => {
return {
    entry: { main: './src/index.js' },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'main.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "html-loader",
                        options: {minimize: true}
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
                use: [
                    devMode ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader'
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: "[path][name].[hash].[ext]",
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: "./public/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html"
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: devMode ? '[name].css' : '[name].[hash].css',
            chunkFilename: devMode ? '[id].css' : '[id].[hash].css',
        }),
    ],
    devtool: devMode ? 'cheap-module-eval-source-map' : 'source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        historyApiFallback: true,
    },
};
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `inject: false` to my HtmlWebPackPlugin:

```
new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            inject: false,
            template: "./public/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html"
        }),
```

And included the `main.js` in the index.html file:

Answer (score 1):

Webpack generate **main.js** file in **dist/** folder. You subpage requests it in **admin/** folder. Open the **HTML** file that represents this page and change the path.

Comment: Thing is I haven't included the main.js in the HTML file, since webpack does that for you. And I also have some pages that are not under /admin/.

Comment: EDIT: I tried to add the main.js in the HTML but then I got double usage, one that webpack automatically adds and the one I specified in the HTML file

Comment: @peter double usage? How can it be? If you set the path to **dist/main.js** it will work.  By the way, do you use **react-router**?

Comment: I got the following in my index.html when running webpack dev server:
<script src=/main.js></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

So one crashes after I reload when I am in /admin/....
Yes, I use react-router, do I need to config anything there?

Comment: Why are you including **main.js** twice? In the first case you use **absolute path** and in the second case you use **relative path**

Comment: The app breaks as it cannot find **main.js** using relative path. If these 2 .js files are the same, just delete the relative one.

Comment: That was the point, the relative path is the one that webpack automatically adds. I used the inject: false method below in order to make it disappear